# When I Write to NetworkStream of TcpClient when data gets sent?

Tags: c#, .net

Having code like

```
            var stream = _tcpClient.GetStream();
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, message);
```

Where `Serialize` can possibly call `Write` byte by byte I get a little affraid - when `stream` will send data to server? will it lock to send on each byte? Shall I call `flush` to ensure all data is sent? Would it be more effective to write to `MemoryStream` and than Write entire Byte array to `stream`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at the [`NoDelay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay.aspx) property. As long as that's false (which is the default), TcpClient won't send a packet on every call to Write. It'll buffer up and only send a full packet when it feels the time is right. Some tweaking of SendBufferSize might also help.

`NetworkStream.Flush` is documented to do nothing.

And as far as locking -- don't worry about that until your profiler has told you that's a problem. :-)

Comment: And I should mention, at least in .NET 4.5, I don't see any locks taken by the stream, but I could have missed one.